# What is the difference between $f(xy)$ and $f(x)f(y)$?

Tags: functions

Like the title says, I have no clue what the difference is and need assistance. If the full question helps it is:
If $f(x) = ax^n$, $a$ is not equal to zero and $f(xy) =f(x)f(y)$, what is the value of $a$?

Comment: First one is multiply $x$ and $y$ together and apply $f$.  Second one is apply $f$ to $x$ and $y$ individually, then multiply the results together.  In general they are not the same.

Answer (score 2):

$f(xy)=a(xy)^n$ whereas $f(x)f(y)=ax^nay^n=a^2(xy)^n$. Thus $a(xy)^n=a^2(xy)^n$. If this equality holds for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$, then $a=a^2$ and thus $a=1$.